# How to pass a paramter of type enum to a method in .h and .m file

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

In the below code I am trying to define an enum and pass parameter of its type to a the method mentioned below.
Also I created a property of same type of the enum

```
    @property (readonly, nonatomic) enum adherance adheranceType;
```

So that the developer can have access to the values of the enum and pass it to the method.
However, I receive an error :

```
expression is not an integer constant expression.
```

Please let me know how to fix it

**.m**

```
    @interface PlaceView ()
@end

@implementation PlaceView
@synthesize adheranceType;

-(float)placeViews:(NSArray *)uiviews WithAdereanceType:(enum adherance) atype {
 NSInteger iter = 0;
        float totalHeight = 0.0f;

        for (UIView *v in uiviews) {
          if (!v.hidden) {
            if (++iter == 1) {
            totalHeight += totalHeight;
        } else {

            switch (atype) {
                case adheranceType == atype:
                    break;
            }
        }

       }
  }
   return 2.0f;
}
```

**.h**

```
enum adherance {
    FIT_SEAMLESS,
 LOOSE_WITH_GAP,
    TIGHT_OVERLAP
};

@interface PlaceView : NSObject { }

@property (readonly, nonatomic) enum adherance adheranceType;

- (float) placeViews:(NSArray *)uiviews WithAdereanceType: (enum adherance) atype;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove enum keyword from property declaration and from parameter

@interface PlaceView : NSObject { }

@property (readonly, nonatomic)  adherance adheranceType;

- (float) placeViews:(NSArray *)uiviews WithAdereanceType: (adherance) atype;
  @end

Comment: but i received error says, Must use -enum- type??!!

Answer (score 0):

define your enum like so:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, adherance) {
  FIT_SEAMLESS = 0,
  LOOSE_WITH_GAP,
  TIGHT_OVERLAP
};
```

define your header like so:

```
@property (readonly, nonatomic) adherance adheranceType;

- (float) placeViews:(NSArray *)uiviews WithAdereanceType:(adherance) atype;
```

inside your .m file do this:

```
-(float)placeViews:(NSArray *)uiviews WithAdereanceType:(adherance) atype {
 NSInteger iter = 0;
        float totalHeight = 0.0f;

        for (UIView *v in uiviews) {
          if (!v.hidden) {
            if (++iter == 1) {
            totalHeight += totalHeight;
        } else {

            switch (atype) {
                case FIT_SEAMLESS:
                    break;
              case LOOSE_WITH_GAP:
                    break;
              case TIGHT_OVERLAP:
                    break;
            }
        }

       }
  }
   return 2.0f;
}
```

good luck